# Macro defining environment

Tags: macros, environments

How to write an environment such that

```
\begin{comment}
    Bla, bla.
\end{comment}
```

produces no output, and instead defines a macro `\@comment` whose
replacement text is everything that is inside the `comment` environment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `environ` package collects the environment into a macro `\BODY`, which you can save as whatever macro name you like (note: must be a global definition, since the envrionment is inside a group).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{environ}
\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{comment}{
  \global\let\@comment\BODY
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{comment}
  Bla, bla.
\end{comment}
\makeatletter\texttt{\meaning\@comment}\makeatother
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: You were two minutes earlier with the same example file. I have added an image and `\texttt` (the only difference) to match the image of my file.

Comment: An entertaining coincidence!

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\appto\endcomment{replacement text}

\begin{document}

text

\begin{comment}
ignored
\end{comment}

\end{document}
```